# Magento 2 custom payment method is not showing in front end

Tags: magento, magento2

I have tried to create new payment method in Magento 2. When I tried to configure it, it is coming in the back end, but not in the front end. If anyone has fixed this issue, please let me know the fixes.

My block form for Quickpay.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Quickpay\Block\Form;

/**
 * Block for Quickpay payment method form
 */
class Quickpay extends \Magento\Quickpay\Block\Form\AbstractInstruction
{
    /**
     * Cash on delivery template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'form/quickpay.phtml';
}
```

AbstractInstuction.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Quickpay\Block\Form;

/**
 * Abstract class for Quickpay payment method form
 */
abstract class AbstractInstruction extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Form
{
    /**
     * Instructions text
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_instructions;

    /**
     * Get instructions text from config
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getInstructions()
    {
        if ($this->_instructions === null) {
            /** @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod $method */
            $method = $this->getMethod();
            $this->_instructions = $method->getConfigData('instructions');
        }
        return $this->_instructions;
    }
}
```

Model Quickpay.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Quickpay\Model;

/**
 * Quickpay payment method model
 *
 * @method \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentMethodExtensionInterface getExtensionAttributes()
 */
class Quickpay extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{
    const PAYMENT_METHOD_QUICKPAY_CODE = 'quickpay';

    /**
     * Payment method code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = self::PAYMENT_METHOD_QUICKPAY_CODE;

    /**
     * Cash On Delivery payment block paths
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_formBlockType = 'Magento\Quickpay\Block\Form\Quickpay';

    /**
     * Info instructions block path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_infoBlockType = 'Magento\Payment\Block\Info\Instructions';

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isOffline = true;

    /**
     * Get instructions text from config
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInstructions()
    {
        return trim($this->getConfigData('instructions'));
    }
}
```

view adminhtml/templates/form/quickpay.html

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Quickpay\Block\Form\Quickpay
 */
$instructions = $block->getInstructions();
?>
<?php if ($instructions): ?>
    <?php $methodCode = $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethodCode());?>
    <ul class="form-list checkout-agreements" id="payment_form_<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $methodCode ?>" style="display:none;">
        <li>
            <div class="<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $methodCode ?>-instructions-content checkout-agreement-item-content">
                <?php /* @noEscape */ echo nl2br($block->escapeHtml($instructions)) ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="offline-payments" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/offline-payments</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="quickpay" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>                                                               
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

view/frontend/templates/form/quickpay.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Quickpay\Block\Form\Quickpay
 */
$instructions = $block->getInstructions();
?>
<?php if ($instructions): ?>
    <?php $methodCode = $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethodCode());?>
    <div class="items <?php /* @noEscape */ echo $methodCode ?> instructions agreement" id="payment_form_<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $methodCode ?>" style="display: none;">
        <?php /* @noEscape */ echo nl2br($block->escapeHtml($instructions)) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

view/frontend/web/template/payment/quickpay.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'quickpay',
                component: 'Magento_Quickpay/js/view/payment/method-renderer/quickpay-method'
            }
        );
        /** Add view logic here if needed */
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

Comment: make sure to deploy the files

Comment: Hi Emizen i have done that also. No luck

Comment: where is `quickpay-method.js` file?